# Facing Error when trying to use QuickBooks Online PHP SDK

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I tried to run the samples, but this error keeps coming up:

> PHP Fatal error: Arrays are not allowed in class constants in
> /home/sample/public_html/temp/test/quickbook/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-6.0.0/src/Core/CoreConstants.php
> on line 17.

I downloaded the source code and is running their samples.

Is there any way to fix this error?
I am running this sample:

```
<?php
//Replace the line with require "vendor/autoload.php" if you are using the Samples from outside of _Samples folder
include('../config.php');

use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\ServiceContext;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\PlatformService\PlatformService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\Http\Serialization\XmlObjectSerializer;


$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
  'auth_mode'       => 'oauth2',
  'ClientID'        => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  'ClientSecret'    => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  'accessTokenKey'  => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  'refreshTokenKey' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'QBORealmID'      => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  'baseUrl'         => "development"
));

$dataService->setLogLocation("/newFolderForLog");


$OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();

$accessToken = $OAuth2LoginHelper->refreshToken();
$error = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getLastError();
if ($error) {
    echo "The Status code is: " . $error->getHttpStatusCode() . "\n";
    echo "The Helper message is: " . $error->getOAuthHelperError() . "\n";
    echo "The Response message is: " . $error->getResponseBody() . "\n";
    return;
}
$dataService->updateOAuth2Token($accessToken);


$dataService->setLogLocation("/Users/hlu2/Desktop/newFolderForLog");

// Iterate through all Accounts, even if it takes multiple pages
$i = 1;
while (1) {
    $allAccounts = $dataService->FindAll('Account', $i, 500);
    $error = $dataService->getLastError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "The Status code is: " . $error->getHttpStatusCode() . "\n";
        echo "The Helper message is: " . $error->getOAuthHelperError() . "\n";
        echo "The Response message is: " . $error->getResponseBody() . "\n";
        exit();
    }

    if (!$allAccounts || (0==count($allAccounts))) {
        break;
    }

    foreach ($allAccounts as $oneAccount) {
        echo "Account[".($i++)."]: {$oneAccount->Name}\n";
        echo "\t * Id: [{$oneAccount->Id}]\n";
        echo "\t * AccountType: [{$oneAccount->AccountType}]\n";
        echo "\t * AccountSubType: [{$oneAccount->AccountSubType}]\n";
        echo "\t * Active: [{$oneAccount->Active}]\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
}

/*

Example output:

Account[0]: Travel Meals
     * Id: NG:42315
     * AccountType: Expense
     * AccountSubType:

Account[1]: COGs
     * Id: NG:40450
     * AccountType: Cost of Goods Sold
     * AccountSubType:

...

*/
```

Comment: Is that code output from file `CoreConstants.php`? ... Doesn't look like a bunch of constants, what is line 17? Also, what is your PHP version?

Comment: Hi, that is my own code. My version is 5.4.45

Comment: That is the issue then, the syntax that is giving you the error is supported from PHP v5.6+.